# Finding ratio of grouped data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I'd like to find ratios after grouping data by QY and Column2.

In every quarter ratio = count of( B/(B+C) ) to be calculated, i.e. in 1-2021 the ratio is 2000/(2000+3000)=0.4.

Grouped data is as follows:

| QY | Column 2 | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-2021 | A | 1000 |
| 1-2021 | B | 2000 |
| 1-2021 | C | 3000 |
| 2-2021 | A | 5000 |
| 2-2021 | B | 3000 |
| 2-2021 | C | 4000 |

Could you kindly help me with the script in postgres?

Comment: Please modify your question in such a way that it is more readable. Also add code that you have tried to do, and specify exactly what your problem is. The SO community does not usually welcome questions that are not well crafted and have not been worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SUM and FILTER to get the records that you need. Something like this should work:

```
WITH table_name(q, x, y) AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM
    (VALUES
        ('1-2021','A',  1000),
    ('1-2021','B',  2000),
    ('1-2021','C',  3000),
    ('2-2021','A',  5000),
    ('2-2021','B',  3000),
    ('2-2021','C',  4000) 
    )s
)
SELECT  q
    ,   ROUND(
            SUM(y)  FILTER(WHERE x = 'B')
            /   CAST(SUM(y) AS DECIMAL) 
        ,2) AS ratio
FROM    table_name
WHERE   x IN('B','C')
GROUP BY q
ORDER BY q;
```

The CTE is there just to simulate an existing table, just for testing.